# Redefine command inside page header

Tags: macros, header-footer, scoping

I’d like to redefine a command inside a page header that’s generated using `scrheading`. The reason for this is that the page header should be in all-low-caps; however the chapter header happens to contain a custom command which changes the *font size*. I need to undo this font size change inside the header only.

Here’s an MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[markcase=lower]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*\lowsc[1]{\texorpdfstring{\protect\scalebox{0.8}{#1}}{#1}}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\renewcommand*\headfont{%
    \scshape%
    \renewcommand*\lowsc[1]{##1}}

\newcommand\itex{\lowsc{i}\textsc{tex}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{\itex{} test}

\clearpage
Some text. \itex{}.
\end{document}
```

The expected output here would be that the header on page 2 looks like this:

[image: expected]

Instead, it looks like this:

[image: actual]

As the `\itex` example shows, the `\lowsc` macro is used in conjuction with `\textsc` to style an abbreviation in small caps, but with intermittent lower-case letters. Without the `\lowsc` macro, these would look too large next to the small caps letters.

The `\renewcommand*\lowsc` inside the `\headfont` seems to have no effect. If I use `\gdef` (or some custom `\grenewcommand` macro) instead, it works. However, that redefines the command *globally*, so that subsequent uses in the main text are also changed, which they shouldn’t be. This looks like a scoping issue to me but I’m honestly at a complete loss why my (non-globally) redefined macro isn’t applied.

Comment: Your itex command is not robust and so already expanded in the header. Use `\DeclareRobustCommand\itex{\lowsc{i}\textsc{tex}}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to how you defined `\lowsc`, the redefinition in the header applies to nothing, because what TeX sees at that point is not `\lowsc` any more, but `\scalebox{0.8}{i}`.

Using `\DeclareRobustCommand` for `\lowsc` solves the problem. I'd use a conditional, however.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[markcase=lower]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newif\ifinheader
\DeclareRobustCommand\lowsc[1]{%
  \ifinheader
    #1%
  \else
    \texorpdfstring{\scalebox{0.8}{#1}}{#1}%
  \fi
}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\renewcommand*\headfont{%
    \scshape\inheadertrue
}

\newcommand\itex{\lowsc{i}\textsc{tex}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{\itex{} test}

\clearpage
Some text. \itex{}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: FWIW I tried the conditional first (exactly as you did, down to the name of the `if`) — it didn’t work. Which figures, `\foobartrue` just redefines `iffoobar`, so it’s similar to just redefining the actual command. So is the actual solution to use `DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, exactly so.